# T-SQL SUBSTRING at certain places

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following example.

```
DECLARE @String varchar(100) = 'GAME_20131011_Set - SET_20131012_Game'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,0,CHARINDEX('_',@String))
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('- ',@STRING),CHARINDEX('_',@STRING))
```

I want to get the words 'GAME' and 'SET' (the first word before the first '_' from both sides of ' - '.

I am getting 'GAME' but having trouble with 'SET'

UPDATE: 'GAME' and 'SET' are just examples, those words may vary.

```
DECLARE @String1 varchar(100) = 'GAMEE_20131011_Set - SET_20131012_Game' -- Looking for 'GAME' and 'SET'
DECLARE @String2 varchar(100) = 'GAMEE_20131011_Set - SETT_20131012_Game' -- Looking for 'GAMEE' and 'SETT'
DECLARE @String2 varchar(100) = 'GAMEEEEE_20131011_Set - SETTEEEEEEEE_20131012_Game' -- Looking for 'GAMEEEEE' and 'SETTEEEEEEEE'
```

Comment: Try running `SELECT CHARINDEX('- ',@STRING)` to see what index it's actually giving you and adjust appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your two parts will always be separated be a specific character (`-` in your example), you could try splitting on that value:

```
DECLARE @String varchar(100) = 'GAME_20131011_Set - SET_20131012_Game'

DECLARE @Left varchar(100), 
        @Right varchar(100)

-- split into two strings based on a delimeter
SELECT @Left = RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, 0, CHARINDEX('-',@String)))
SELECT @Right = LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@String, CHARINDEX('-',@String)+1, LEN(@String)))

-- handle the strings individually
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Left, 0, CHARINDEX('_', @Left))
SELECT SUBSTRING(@Right, 0, CHARINDEX('_', @Right))

-- Outputs: 
--    GAME
--    SET
```

Here's a SQLFiddle example of this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22594

The issue that you are running into with your original query is that you are specifying `CHARINDEX('- ', @String)` for your start index, which will include `-` in any substring starting at that point. Also, with `CHARINDEX('_',@STRING)` for your length parameter, you will always end up with the index of the *first* `_` character in the string.

By splitting the original string in two, you avoid these problems.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,0,CHARINDEX('_',@String))
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String,CHARINDEX('- ',@STRING)+1, CHARINDEX('_',@STRING)-1)
```

Comment: The `CHARINDEX('_',@STRING)` is going to give you the index of the `_` after `GAME` (i.e., this one: `GAME_`)

Comment: thx for your post. I tried but running into issues when names are diff. Would you know how to make this dynamic?

Comment: are you not trying to extract anyword where GAME is in this 1st string 'GAME_20131011_Set'  and SET from this 2nd string 'SET_20131012_Game' ?? I mean any words in place of GAME and SET in respective strings ??

Answer (score 1):

`charindex` takes an optional third parameter that says which poistion in the string to start the search from. You could roll this into one statement, but it's easier to read with three

```
Declare @start int = charindex('-', @string) + 2;
Declare @end int = charindex('_', @string, @start);

Select substring(@string, @start, @end - @start);
```

**<kbd>[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/8896)</kbd>**

Comment: @user1569220 I've linked an example.